# Insert ignore multiple value in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server

I have this MySQL query on nodejs to insert ignore multiple values:

```
connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO output VALUES ?', [values], function ( err, rows, fields ){...}
```

Now I want to migrate the database from MySQL to SQL Server, and the above query no longer works on SQL Server. The example I found is using the `NOT EXIST` statement, but I don't understand how can I use `NOT EXIST` to check multiple values. Thank you!

Comment: In SQL Server you may try to convert parameters array transferred into VALUES clause into a pseudo-table in CTE (WITH clause). Then use INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: okay, i think i should try to do this one, never think of that before. thank you for your answer

Comment: @Akina It works, took me hours to do it haha. thank you again!

Comment: Can you put the correction on, please?